# Cannot add default gateway

Tags: linux, routing

Getting the following error when trying to add a default gateway for `eth1`.

```
# route add default gw 192.168.228.2 eth1
route: SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

Can't figure out why.

Comment: what is the output of `ip link` and `ip route`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a route to 192.168.228.2.  Likely your address is not in the 192.168.228 block, or your netmask is to restrictive to reach it.

Answer (score 1):

The network cable could be disconnected. Try to ping a known IP first, then try to ping the IP of the gateway and see what happens.